# How do I create an NSLocale from a Country Code?

Tags: ios, nslocale

I'm trying to create an NSLocale based on the location of an iOS device. From the device, I can get a `CLLocation`. From the `CLLocation`, I can get `[CLPlacemark]`. From one of the `[CLPlacemark]`, I can get the `ISOcountryCode`, but I don't know how to use this to create an NSLocale.

When I do this my country code is "GB". The `availableLocaleIdentifiers()` that contain "GB" are "kw_GB", "gd_GB", "en_GB" and "cy_GB". I think the identifier I want, in this case, is en_GB, but how to I programatically choose this?

Comment: You need a language too for the locale, not just a country. Many countries have more than one locale due to several languages in that country.

Comment: I'm just looking to present an amount of money in the correct format for the country so does it matter which of those identifiers i choose? Would it be okay to just pick one at random?

Comment: It might matter. Depends on the locale. You could write a test app that formats a currency value for each locale within a given country and see if any one is different from the others.

Comment: It turns out that they do vary considerably. I might need to give this whole problem rethink. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could get the language from the user's actual locale. I know I'd like to see things in English no matter where I happen to be at the moment.

Comment: That would be fine with "GB" (in the case that the user speaks English) but not fine with "JP" for example, as there's no "en_JP" identifier. In that case, I think I'd like to take the principal language of the country. Now how to find that out...